# What does a "User needs to accept terms of service" 401 error mean?

Tags: box-api

We will occasionally get this error message:

```
User needs to accept terms of service
```

when making API calls. Replaying the calls will work later on. What does this error message mean exactly and is there a way we can avoid it?

Comment: This would suggest that the account isn't active because the user hasn't yet agreed to the terms of service. How much later is 'later'?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, this is the pattern.
`API calls works - n times | 
API call fails a few times with that error message |
API calls work again - m times`

Comment: Are these managed users -- i.e. part of an enterprise? Have you just created them?

Comment: They might be part of Box enterprise, I'm not sure. The user is not just created, no. It is using the same OAuth connection throughout all API calls, however, so the intermittent behaviour seems weird to me for any user.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this when a user was created (by an admin or via the API), an email was sent to the user and the user needs to confirm their email and agree to the ToS, and then I tried to impersonate that user via the API before the user agreed to the ToS.